# What happens to Coulomb's law at small distances?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, singularities, coulombs-law, approximations

I searched in the forum and found the maximum distance is $r=1.75\times 10^{-15} 
m$.  Ok, imagine an electron hits a plate with charge of 1 proton, the result of Coulomb's law is $230$ Newtons. Obviously it has an error, is the distance $r=1.75\times10^{-15} m$ wrong? I think the distance should be much larger to validate Coulomb's law.

Comment: Do you know that the distance in your question is approximately the diameter of a proton?  What kind of material do you imagine your plate to be made of?

Comment: yes but, what about the type of material? How does that influence the distance?

Comment: My point is that such a material does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's formulation is a bit irritating, but the answer is that for very small distances, Coulomb's law does no longer apply. One needs to consider **QED**, the quantum version of electrodynamics. Feynman has a nice, popular book about that. It's called "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter"